# Set Twig variable inside an include and use it afterward

Tags: php, global-variables, twig, template-engine

imagine you have a twig template (tplA.twig) that include an other one

```
<p>Twig template A</p>

{% set test = "in tpl A" %}
<p>first, variable is: {{ test }}</p>

{% include "tplB.twig" %}
<p>and the variable is: {{ test }}</p>
```

and the included template (tplB.twig)

```
<div>Content of tpl B</div>
{% set test = "now is tpl B" %}
```

What is the best way to set/change a variable in an included template and use it in the master template? How to use globals? Note that I can't use blocks and extends, and I'm not using Symfony.

Many thanks

**EDIT**

The real context is a *very basic* multilingual structure. For a page, I have one master template:

```
<h1>{{ i18n('mainTitle') }}</h1>
<h2>current language (fr, en): {{ ln }}</h2>

<!-- here a list of photos, but not in a foreach loop -->
<div>
    <div>
        <img src="/same/for/all/languages-a.jpg" alt="localized A" />
        <span>localized A</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="/same/for/all/languages-b.jpg" alt="localized B" />
        <span>localized B</span>
    </div>
    <!-- etc. -->
</div>
```

It is a very small website, so I didn't created a complex structure with database, and I wanted to manage all this stuff in the template.

The thing is: how is it possible to display the right localized strings? What I thought about was to include a localized template, to separate concerns. Something like:

```
<!-- before the photos list -->
{% include ln ~ '/photos-list.twig' %}
<!-- then the photos list -->
```

And inside this template, I would have setted all the variables in the right locale, so I could use them in my photos list. (as explained in the first part of my question)

*note that I have this structure for all others pages. Text content is separated in the locale folder, and each page has a master template (again, it's a very basic personal website)*

What I did finally was to insert a hudge *if* statement before the photos list. If locale is *fr*, set variables with french texts, if it's *en*, set variables with english texts.

That does the trick, so I'm ok with that ^^

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36919869/include-a-twig-file-and-pass-variables-from-a-separate-file/37011064#37011064

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you move the second call of `{{ test }}` in `tplB` ( for this occasion ) ?

`<div>Content of tpl B</div>
{% set test = "now is tpl B" %}
<p>and the variable is: {{ test }}</p>`